# Создание таблицы с доп подгрузкой данных

Tags: android-sdk, android

Приветствую, уважаемые хешкодовцы!

Есть следующая задача. Пользователи IOS часто видят, особенно это актуально в IOS 7 , доп подгрузку данных в таблицу. Т.е. таблица обновляется если просто сдвинуть резко палец вниз (проводя по таблице) вниз. И тогда, сверху появляется progress и табличка обновляется.

Вообщем хочу сделать нечто подобное под Android.

P.S. Думаю что уже есть готовые решения на github, но к сожалению я не нашел (видимо плохо искал).

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh